# Why can't std::variant find operator<() when not in same namespace as compared classes

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

I was trying to provide a custom `operator<` for a class from an external library. This class is within that library's namespace, however, the operator I wanted to define is not. Now if I define a `std::variant` and want to use it in a `std::set`, the compilation fails as it can't detect the `operator<`. Here's an example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/iC-afz)):

```
#include <variant>
#include <set>
#include <string>

namespace myClasses
{
struct classA
{
    classA(const unsigned int i) :i(i) {};
    int i;
};

struct classB
{
    classB(const unsigned int u) :u(u) {};
    unsigned int u;
};

}// namespace myClasses

//namespace myClasses { //<- uncomment this

bool operator<(const myClasses::classA &v, const myClasses::classA &w)
{
    return v.i < w.i;
}


bool operator<(const myClasses::classB &v, const myClasses::classB &w)
{
    return v.u < w.u;
}

//} //<- and uncomment this

using var_t = std::variant<myClasses::classA, myClasses::classB>;

int main()
{
    std::set<var_t> myset;

    myset.emplace(myClasses::classB(1));
    myset.emplace(myClasses::classA(2));

    return 0;
}
```

If you put the `operator<`s in the namespace `myClasses` it compiles fine.
Can someone explain to me, why my original attempt failed? If I just compare 
`myClasses::classA(1) < myClasses::classA(2)`, there's no need to put the operators in the `myClasses` namespace.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an feature of argument dependent lookup (ADL), which you are relying on when the operator is search for from `std::variant`.

When searching for free functions, including overloaded operators, the compiler will only search in namespaces related to the arguments to the function in question.

There are more details in [this cppreference article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Where you call the comparison directly from your code, at the same namespace scope as the `operator<` declarations, "normal" (i.e. non-ADL) lookup can find the operator definition directly.

Comment: "Where you call the comparison directly from your code, at the same namespace scope as the operator< declarations" no, this also works if you do it from a namespace nested in `::`. The reason is that `std::` has `operator<` defined, and unqualified lookup stops there after finding it (and it doesn't match).